# Populating an object from an SQL Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6

I want to populate my Master Detail object with data from an SQL Server query.

However I don't seem to form the Detail part of the query correctly.

Is it even possible?

I have the following classes

```
public class OrderCountReportHeader : IMyReport 
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime RunAt { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderCountReportDetail> Details { get; set; }

}

public class OrderCountReportDetail {
    public virtual OrderBankReportHeader Header { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int  Quantity { get; set; }
```

}

and I want to populate an instance of OrderCountReportHeader from the output of an SQL Query

```
private static string ReportSql() {

        return @" 
                SET NOCOUNT ON;
                select 1 as Id, getdate() as RunAt, 'test' as Name;
                select 'RC' as ProductCode , 5 as Quantity; "
            ;
    }

var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<OrderCountReportHeader>(sql).ToArray()[0];

    Assert.AreEqual(@"test", s.Name);   // true
    Assert.AreEqual("RC", s.Details[0].ProductCode); // fails because Details is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using two separate calls to SqlQuery
though I would be pleased to know a better way.

```
    var header = connect.Database.SqlQuery<OrderCountReportHeader>(ReportSqlHeader()).ToArray()[0];

            var details = connect.Database.SqlQuery<OrderCountReportDetail>(ReportSqlDetails()).ToList();
            foreach (var det in details)
            {
                det.Header = header;
            }
            header.Details = details;
```